# ASP.NET Membership/Roles/FormsAuth - how can I login as a super-user?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm working on a web application that uses the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and Roles providers with Forms Authentication. There are various roles in the system. I need to have a user role that is essentially a super-user that can "login" as any user account (in effect impersonating the user).

Does anyone know if this is possible using the providers? Any ideas?

One approach I was thinking of was to logout the super-user and sign them in as the desired user with

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

And adding a variable to their Session to flag them as a super-user. I think this would work, but I was just wondering if there's a smarter way to do it without directly using the Session object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net approach doesn't support the concept, so you are right on trying to find an alternate way.
Something that you can do is add the IsSuperUser info to the authentication ticket UserData property.

Comment: Thanks Freddy, I think I will go with this suggestion. Storing this information in the authentication ticket seems the most correct place for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a SuperUser role that can do anything? Then the user can be just part of that role.

If what you really need to have is an ability for an administrator to impersonate someone else, I don't know what is the additional flag for? If it marks the currently logged in user giving him super powers the same will be achieved by setting up a role. If you, however, need to just impersonate someone else (e.g. this is help desk and you need to see exactly the same as the end user sees) - I would just check the credentials normally, then check if a superuser is logging in and who they want to impersonate and based on that just authenticate the logging in user as the one that he's willing to impersonate.

I hope what I wrote makes sense...

Comment: Hi Pawel. Thanks for your feedback. I mightn't have explained it properly - the site uses Personalisation so that a view is different for each user and this is leveraged by using HttpContext.Current.User.I need this to be the logged-in user, but also know that it is a super-user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.  Sorry no graphics, on ipad here in bed...

1) use claims based architecture.  Its easy to implement, see my project.

2) essentially impersonated user will have a second identity on the claims principal object, but will have different realm (realm may be wrong word, the string you use to create the identity)

3) You can construct the identity of the impersonated user and manually build their claims.... They should get written to the token immediately.  I would look at a generic Claims Transformer class to do this.

4) You may need to adjust the way the site behaves, based on the presence of a impersonated identity, but thats the fun part.

Working WIF implementation
https://github.com/wcpro/scaffr-generated